# In Caffe2, is there any caffemodel that deals with the chatbot conversation

Tags: caffe, caffe2

In Caffe2, is there any caffemodel that deals with the chatbot conversation. 
Is there any model that helps to work with the text classification / analysis

Is there any DNN example / sample that deals with the text statements as given in the Caffe2 (https://caffe2.ai/docs/applications-of-deep-learning.html)

"As more complex bots are written using DNN, their ability to understand your statements, and more importantly, 
the context, the bots will be able to hold longer, more meaningful conversations without you even realizing you are not chatting with a real person."

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/tree/master/caffe2/python/models/seq2seq

I have used this model for translation.

Comment: hi.. thanks for your reply but I am looking for the model that deals with the text analyzer / classifer. I am not sure this translate model will help. can you please suggest me how to handle this...